# Multiline supression with cppcheck

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I would like to use multiline suppression in cppcheck.
Is that possible?
For example:
I would like to change

```
// cppcheck-suppress unusedFunction
int fn1(){
    return 42;
}
// cppcheck-suppress unusedFunction
int fn2(){
}
// cppcheck-suppress unusedFunction
int fn3(){
}
int main(){
}
```

to something like:

```
// cppcheck-suppress-start unusedFunction
int fn1(){
    return 42;
}
int fn2(){
}
int fn3(){
}
// cppcheck-suppress-end unusedFunction
int main(){
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; per [the manual](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf), inline suppressions have no "begin"/"end" equivalent syntax.

However, there are other ways to set suppressions; if you wanted to use `unusedFunction` throughout a whole source file, for example, you can say that in a suppressions file.

Refer to chapter 6 in the above linked manual.